# Geth VerifySeal function

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a question regarding `VerifySeal` function in Geth source code. If I understood correctly, it verifies if block has valid seal regarding the PoW algorithm. The arguments that function takes are `chainReader` and block header. Is there a way to get the body of the block that is being verified? I know that `chainReader` has method `GetBlock()`, but it needs the hash of the block and I don't know how to obtain it. On the other hand, I'm not sure if the block that is being verified is on the blockhain yet, so perhaps this method won't even work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q1:** I have a question regarding VerifySeal function in Geth source code.
>   If I understood correctly, it verifies if block has valid seal
>   regarding the PoW algorithm. The arguments that function takes are
>   chainReader and block header. Is there a way to get the body of the
>   block that is being verified? I know that chainReader has method
>   GetBlock(), but it needs the hash of the block and I don't know how to
>   obtain it

As code comment, you can see that the `VerifySeal()` only verify the header including the nonce of PoW algorithm as you mentioned. So getting block body is not necessary for this method.

```
// VerifySeal checks whether the crypto seal on a header is valid according to
// the consensus rules of the given engine.
VerifySeal(chain ChainReader, header *types.Header) error
```

full block data need when sealing as in below `Seal()` method; because it need to calculate the merkle tree root hash `transactionsRoot` for all the transactions in the block.

```
// Seal generates a new block for the given input block with the local miner's
// seal place on top.
Seal(chain ChainReader, block *types.Block, stop <-chan struct{}) (*types.Block, error)
```

> **Q2:** On the other hand, I'm not sure if the block that is being verified is
>   on the blockhain yet, so perhaps this method won't even work?

When a node receive block from a remote node, it need to verify all the things such as block header, block body and it replay all the transactions in the block to validate the state as well. You can find more detail by drill down into `github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go` source code

```
// insertChain will execute the actual chain insertion and event aggregation. The
// only reason this method exists as a separate one is to make locking cleaner
// with deferred statements.
func (bc *BlockChain) insertChain(chain types.Blocks) (int, []interface{}, []*types.Log, error)
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for ansewrs. I have another regarding Q1. Aren't transactions neccesary for calculating seal when mining (and thus verifying)? The comments are clear, but it seems that I missed something. Thanks again.

Comment: When block sealing, transactions are necessary. because the limitation of comment then I updated the answer. PTAL.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still have a question, though  (thanks for helping me). I fail to see where are those roots crated. I'm looking at sealer.go file. I only see header used for sealing (Seal and mine methods). Obviously, I'm missing something... Also, the root that you are refering to is TxHash field in header?

Comment: yes, it's the `TxHash` in the source code

Comment: So it is enough to have header with `TxHash` to calculate nonce?

Comment: Actually; miner need to find a nonce to make diggest of the header to meet A target value by trying/error mechanism. The nonce and tx hash was included in the header.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Things are clearer for me. Just one more thing, and I won't bother you anymore :) Just to be certain, TxHash value is the only thing in mining process that depends on transactions?

Comment: basically yes. By the way, the output of the transactions will make two another root hash: state root and receipt root that you can find detail document somewhere in the internet :)

Comment: Thank you, too! Your question urge me to spend time to research more about the go-ethereum also :)